# Is there a way to have a Check Mark box that if selected it will cross out the entire line of text?

Tags: excel, checkbox, strikethrough

I am trying to have an Excel spreadsheet that has a column of Check Boxes.  I would like for when the check mark box is checked then the whole row of text is then crossed off.  As in I checked a box to signify that the action was completed but then strikes through all the data in that row.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `x` serves as a check mark and the 'boxes' for it are cells in ColumnX, select entire sheet and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=$X1="X"
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select Font, Effects and check Strikethrough, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

For greater visual impact you might want a choose a Font colour at the same time, that is not whatever is in regular use on the sheet.

---

If the check mark is placed with a Check Box (Form Control) the Control Value when Checked could be set to Cell link to say `X1` (X2 for the next box, X3 ... etc). Then the CF formula rule above amended to:

```
=$X1
```

However, revising numerous Control Boxes seems a very long-winded approach, where entry of just `X` (or any other character of choice) would appear to serve.

Comment: Yes - I am trying to have an Excel spreadsheet that has a column of Check Boxes that when checked the strike-through will go through that row of text.

Comment: Is there anyway to check?  I honestly don't remember

Comment: I believe that it is just the regular form controls

Comment: It is a regular form control